# Foxfi and DD-WRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, tethering

I am currently using my phone (Android) for Internet access. I am running FoxFi for WiFi tethering. My goal is to get several devices, both wireless and wired, to communicate over the network and to access the Internet through the tethered WiFi (my phone). I successfully setup a router with DD-WRT as a repeater bridge that accomplishes this when the tethering is enabled. The devices can also communicate after turning the tethering off. However, I want the network devices to be able to communicate without having to enable tethering at all. I have given all the devices on the network static IP addresses. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using two routers. I setup the first router with DD-WRT in [client mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless). It simply pulls the WAN connection from FoxFi. I then hardwired a second router to the first one and used it as I would any other home router. All the PCs and devices on the network connect to the second router.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work without using a second router. I took the same approach as you described in your OP. My phone running foxfi is at address 43.1, and my router is at 43.2. I set the default gateway to 43.2 on all of my devices (as well as using static IP addresses) and they seem to be able to communicate just fine independent of whether or not tethering has been enabled.